# Timing issues when checking for content of multiple text nodes in capybara

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

We're having a quick search field on a page which filters the result list of a previous search via an AJAX call.

We have tried several methods of checking the content of the changed list.

At the beginning, there is a list like e.g. this:

```
<div class="search-list">
  <div class="entry">
    <div class="job-title">Manager</div>
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <div class="job-title">Slave</div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

After the quick search, the whole search `search-list` will be replaced by an AJAX response with the second `entry` div being removed.

We're trying to check this condition with the following statement:

```
page.find('.search-list .job-title').map(&:text) =~ ['Manager']
```

but it only sees the state before the AJAX request has been made. This is probably due to the condition being checked immediately without waiting for the completion of the AJAX request. We have tried several methods, like settings the Selenium driver's `resynchronize` option.

Putting a sleep 10 in front of the above line does work, but is an unclean solution. Currently we have no idea how to get this working, does anyone else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use a helper method using `wait_until` to wait for the ajax to finish, then do my test.

So perhaps something like:

```
page.wait_until { page.evaluate_script "jQuery.active == 0" }
page.find('.search-list .job-title').map(&:text) =~ ['Manager']
```

`wait_until` wait until `true` is returned by the block (though it will timeout after a little bit). You can also pass it a timeout value, `wait_until(5)`, to exit after the time allotted.

You could also possibly up your Capybara wait time.

```
Capybara.default_wait_time = 10
```

---

#### Update for Angular.js

`angular.element.active == 0` works in the same fashion.

*`jQuery.active == 0` stil works within Angular.js, but not sure if that is because I have jQuery as part of my javascript libraries.*